# Flutter: No MediaQuery widget ancestor found

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Calculator());
}

class Calculator extends StatelessWidget {
  final numpad_background_color = Color(0x212121);
  final background_color = Colors.black;
  final equal_button_background_color = Color(0xffbe00);

  final textColor = Colors.white;
  final operatorTextColor = Color(0xf3ba0e);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: appbar(context),
            body: Stack(
              children: [Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.37), numpad(context)],
            )));
  }

  Widget appbar(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(title: Text("Rechner", style: TextStyle(color: textColor, fontSize: 15)), backgroundColor: background_color, leading: Icon(Icons.history));
  }

  Widget numpad(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: numpad_background_color), child:
      Column(children: [

      ],),);
  }
}
```

> Error: No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context
> that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you have
> not added a WidgetsApp, CupertinoApp, or MaterialApp widget (those
> widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you
> use comes from a widget above those widgets.

I don't understand the error, I created a MaterialApp Widget and call MediaQuery from there, why does this error appear?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try creating another widget like this

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Calculator(),
    );
  }
}
```

Then your main method will looks like this

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it changed nothing. My code is now like this: https://pastebin.com/yBw6K8gc

Comment: Sorry, it work's now, it was my mistake. You're my hero, thank you very much! I removed the MaterialApp Widget from Calculator and replaced it with a Scaffold :)

Comment: I'll do that, but I have to wait three more minutes...

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your classname with **MaterialApp** and your issue is solved. Ex. here my classname is **sahim** and that's how i solved this issue.

```
 void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: sahim(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do it as below. I have solved it in this way

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Calculator()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it as below
This worked for me:

```
    void main() {
     runApp(MaterialApp(),);
   }
```

Comment: If the prior answers that used that function with arguments were inefficient  or had other deficiencies then you should explain why your answer is better or more general. Otherwise it appears to be essentially a duplicate.